Combine two comma separated lists to return an array
I have two comma separated lists, company_id and view_all_tickets that were retrieved by an API call from Freshdesk into Zapier and correlate to each other, I need to create an array that I can put back into another API call from Zapier back into Freshdesk but am struggling to do so.
Ultimately, I call information from a contact, if they are already associated to multiple companies in Freshdesk I need to add a new company to the list of companies that they are associated with without removing the existing companies. Freshdesk doesn't have a method to simply ADD to the existing field, it will always REPLACE the existing field so I need to gather the existing fields, add a new one and combine it into a new API PUT call.
Example:
company_id has 48000098316, 48000110432
view_all_tickets has true, false
I need this to return a format as below
{"company_id": 48000098316, "view_all_tickets": true}, {"company_id": 48000110432, "view_all_tickets": false}

I have tried every combination of features in Zapier/Code by Zapier/Formatter that I can think of but haven't found a successful way to get it back in the format I need to so I can use it.
To be fair, I am highly inexperienced, but trying to do this to the best of my ability.

I would use a Python snippet in a Code by Zapier step to create lists from the comma-separated strings by splitting on the comma. Then zip the two lists together since there is an assumption the two comma-separated strings will always be the same length.
From there, you can iterate over the zip object to create the individual records and append those to a new list and finally to a key in the output dictionary to use in a subsequent step where you'll perform your PUT operation:
input_data = {
    'company_id' : '48000098316,48000110432',
    'view_all_tickets' : 'true,false'
}

output = {}

zipped = zip(input_data['company_id'].split(','),input_data['view_all_tickets'].split(','))

records = []
for company_id, ticket in zipped:
    record = {
        'company_id' : company_id,
        'view_all_tickets' : ticket
    }
    records.append(record)
    
output['records'] = records


I REALLY appreciate your assistance, and looking through that it certainly looked like it was going to work for what I needed, but once I looked at the data it produced it seems it isn't creating the final "Records" output in the format as expected, but rather basically as the same two lists it started with... Is there a way to adjust this so the output records are stored as text instead of code?
The issue is that I need to put this back into another API query, and since "company_id" and "view_all_tickets" show up as individual items in the return code the format isn't correct when I try.

Ok, I got it updated to output everything as a string (that was easy by changing "output['records'] = records" to "output['records'] = str(records)" isntead. But when using this in the subsequent API call I'm seeing that the true and false values for "View_all_tickets" is in quotations instead of an actual true false value.
{"other_companies":[{'company_id': '48000098316', 'view_all_tickets': 'False'}, {'company_id': '48000110432', 'view_all_tickets': 'False'}, {'company_id': '48002519816', 'view_all_tickets': 'true'}]}
How can that be fixed?

ok, I got it all figured out. I had to add some additional quotes to the above "record" line, then use a couple of "Formatter" blocks in zapier to remove single quotes and make everything lowercase, but it is working now!

@BenCrider happy to hear you were able to get this across the finish line. Good luck with the rest of the Zap :)

The below completed what I needed to do to use this in an API call, it required some formatting blocks to remove additional quotes that were added and make everything lowercase to the Booleans weren't trying to think they were words.
input_data = {
    'company_id' : '48000098316,48000110432',
    'view_all_tickets' : 'true,false'
}

output = {}

zipped = zip(input_data['company_id'].split(','),input_data['view_all_tickets'].split(','))

records = []
for company_id, ticket in zipped:
    record = {
        "'company_id'" : company_id,
        "'view_all_tickets'" : ticket
    }
    records.append(record)
    
output['records'] = str(records)

